# How to test functional selectors in redux saga?

Tags: javascript, redux, jestjs, redux-saga, ramda.js

Currently it is possible to write reducers and test sagas like this:

```js
// selector
const selectThingById = (state, id) => state.things[id]

// in saga
const thing = yield select(selectThingById, id)

// and test
expect(gen.next().value)
  .toEqual(select(selectThingById, id))
```

However I want to use more functional approach to write my reducers and put data (state) last in arguments:

```js
// selector
const selectThingById = R.curry((id, state) => state.things[id])

// in saga
const thing = yield select(selectThingById(id))

// test: this actually fails
expect(gen.next().value)
  .toEqual(select(selectThingById(id)))
```

The test fails because `selectThingById(id)` creates new function everytime.

This could be solved by option to prepend arguments to `select` instead of apending. Is it possible or is there any way how to test such selectors?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the selector factory using the `call` effect so you can inject the right function to the saga using `gen.next(val)`

```
// in saga
const selector = yield call(selectThingById, id)
const thing = yield select(selector)

// test
const selector = selectThingById(id)
gen.next(selector)
  .toEqual(call(selectThingById, id))
expect(gen.next().value)
  .toEqual(select(selector))
```

Comment: Nice solution! It would be nice to have some utility function around this.

Comment: The is definitely the right approach. A common pitfall for developers new to saga (myself included) is that we create side-effect inside our saga by calling functions directly. This causes sagas to be hard to test. Rember to use the `call` effect so that the saga always promises to do something, but not do it until it is executed by the saga middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Just export your function for importing in your test and put it to `next`:

```
// selector
export const selectThingById = R.curry((id, state) => state.things[id])

// in saga
const thing = yield select(selectThingById(id))

// test
expect(gen.next(selectThingById).value)
  .toEqual(select(selectThingById(id)))
```

Comment: I could not get this to work from the testing side.